# How spark structured streaming process micro batches - one by one or simultaneously

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

I have a question about how micro-batches are processed. Will spark

- get several microbatches for all available executors and process several micro-batches in parallel or
- it will get only one batch and process it and then get another batch

It seems that the second variant is correct, but I'm not sure, I'm new with Spark Structured Streaming

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're asking about Fixed interval micro-batches. From Spark Structured Streaming documentation on the [Fixed interval micro-batches Trigger](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers):

> The query will be executed with micro-batches mode, where micro-batches will be kicked off at the user-specified intervals.
>
> - If the previous micro-batch completes within the interval, then the
>   engine will wait until the interval is over before kicking off the
>   next micro-batch.
> - If the previous micro-batch takes longer than the
>   interval to complete (i.e. if an interval boundary is missed), then
>   the next micro-batch will start as soon as the previous one completes
>   (i.e., it will not wait for the next interval boundary).
> - If no new data is available, then no micro-batch will be kicked off.

The second bullet indicates that micro-batches are processed serially, which is in line with your second variant.